# Video.js not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, video.js

When viewing in IE8 the video shows as a black box and i get the following errors in the console.

LOG: TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'load': object is null or undefined

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'load': object is null or undefined 
video.js, line 47 character 74

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'U': object is null or undefined 
video.js, line 56 character 17

this is the page where you can view the script.
http://solutions.intermec.com/NA-US-CN51

Comment: Did you find any solutions of this problem? Faced with the same issue on IE8...